# For linearized PDF how to determine the length of the cross-reference stream in advance?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdf-parsing

When generating a linearized PDF, a cross-reference table should be stored in the very beginning of the file. If it is a cross-reference stream, this means the content of the table will be compressed and the actual size of the cross-reference stream after compression is unpredictable.

So my question is: 
How to determine the actual size of this cross-reference stream in advance? 
If the actual size of the stream is unpredictable, after the offsets of objects are written into the stream and the stream is written into the file, it will change the actual offsets of the following objects again, won't it? Do I miss something here?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: *it will change the actual offsets of the following objects* - that is why such a cross reference stream generally only contains references to objects before it. Even in linearized PDFs each cross reference table or stream normally only references preceding objects.

Comment: This is true for the normal reference tables, which usually references only preceding objects. But in a linearized PDF, the reference table for the objects on the first page, catalog, etc., follows directly the Linearization Dictionary, which is located before the objects it references. That's why it confuses me.

Comment: Hm. I'd have to look into such a file to be sure, but one way to achieve that may be using compression with an appropriate predictor. This would make the data to be compressed known beforehand with the exception of the first offset. This could make the length of the compressed stream predictable.

Comment: I checked many linearized pdf, usually Predictor 12 (PNG Up) is used in XRefStream, but I don't understand why using a predictor makes the size of compressed data predictable? Could you please explain it a little bit more detailed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I checked some linearized PDFs with XRefStream (saved from Acrobat), all have some whitespace padding around first XRefStream dictionary. Actually, e.g. QPDF source, method called `calculateXrefStreamPadding` has comments that might be interesting to you. And indeed, that padding in files, saved with QPDF tool, is really huge.

Comment: @VadimR, thanks! Whitespace padding seems to be the answer, though it could be big. I also observed big paddings in a few big linearized pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

> How to determine the actual size of this cross-reference stream in advance?

First of all you don't. At least not exactly. You described why.

But it suffices to have an estimate. Just add some bytes to the estimate and later-on pad with whitespaces. @VadimR pointed out that such padding can regularly be observed in linearized PDFs.

You can either use a rough estimate as in the QPDF source @VadimR referenced or you can try for a better one.

You could, e.g. make use of predictors:

At the time you eventually have to create the cross reference streams, all PDF objects can already be serialized in the order you need with the exception of the cross reference streams and the linearization dictionary (which contains the final size of the PDF and some object offsets). Thus, you already know the differences between consecutive xref entry values for most of the entries.

If you use up predictors, you essentially only store those differences. So, you already know most of the data to compress. Changes in a few entries won't change the compressed result too much. So this probably gives you a better estimate.

Furthermore, as the first cross reference stream does not contain too many entries in general, you can try compressing that stream multiple times for different numbers of reserved bytes.

PS: I have no idea what Adobe do use in their linearization code. And I don't know whether it makes sense to fight for a few bytes more or less here; after all linearization is most sensible for big documents for which a few bytes more or less hardly count.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I also observed there are some whitespace padding just after the first XRefStream, it seems padding with whitespace is the solution.